# NodeJS - Generate PDF on the fly with pdfmake

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I would like, in my NodeJS app, to generate a PDF in server-side with pdfmake but i don't know how to do. I would like to don't save it on my server.

I have this

```
const printer = new PdfPrinter( fonts );
const pdfKitDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument( dd );
const stream = pdfKitDoc.pipe( ... );
pdfKitDoc.end();
return stream;
```

and I don't know what I have to type instead of '...'. If it's possible, I would like to stream it as blob to use it in my apps.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You should place a [writable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams) in `...` it depends on your usage what you exactly should pass to use it. E.g. write to a file, save to external storage, convert to buffer for further processing...

Comment: @TheeSritabtim can you show me an example please ? Because I would like to convert it to buffer but I don't know how to do... It's my first NodeJS app and I think I've never created stream

Comment: https://github.com/stream-utils/stream-to-array this should help you, basically create `stream`, pass it to `toArray` and handle as the `Buffer` example, then return the result of `toArray` as a `Promise` for further processing. You can edit the question and include what you have tried if you got stuck

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem thanks to @Thee Sritabtim.

1. Install [stream-to-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-to-array)
2. Then

```js
return toArray( doc ).then( parts => {
   return Buffer.concat( parts );
} );
```